# Rewrite and combine query strings for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, url-rewriting

I'm working with two plugins with a different language query string setup. The language plugin itself works with *mydomain.com/?lang=english* (polylang plugin), the other plugin needs to retrieve *mydomain.com/?language=english*.

How should I rewrite the url so both are working correctly? I've tried the following:

```
   function languagerewrite() {
     //$language = get_query_var('lang', 1); 
     //get_query_var not working, yet 'lang' is registered Why? 
       if(isset($_GET["lang"])) {
       $language = $_GET["lang"];

      echo esc_url(add_query_arg( 'language', $language ));
      }
    }
    add_action('init', 'languagerewrite', 10, 0);
```

This will echo the following:
?lang=english&language=english which should work, although I need to rewrite that to a nice url. 
How can use the printed url? And is this the best way to do this in php or should I rewrite this in htaccess? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use such htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
# two lines to avoid endless redirect. Although you may leave only 1st
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang(.+)language
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !langage(.+)lang
# Looking for lang or language and saving other get values
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+&|)lang(|uage)=([^&]+)(&.+|)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1?%1lang=%3&language=%3%4 [L]
```

To try, add R - [R,L] to see redirect in browser address tab

Comment: Thanks. That's working perfectly. Is it possible to make this also work with pretty urls enabled? When I enable nice permalinks, the polylang will be rewritten like *domain.com/language/english/*, but the /?language query does not work then anymore.

Comment: Please, clear what you suupose as input and want you want to achive? Will you still need lang query?

Comment: Well in short I want to have an url like *domain.com/language/english/*. I tried several things on the rewrite rule but didn't get it correctly yet.

Comment: with query - domain.com/language/english/?lang=english   ? And input url as before - ?lang= or langage= ?

Comment: No without any query. But the language must stay working for both plugins. (so the queries ?lang= or ?language= rewritten to one nice url.

Comment: such htaccess will add language to tail: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+&|)lang(|uage)=([^&]+)(&.+|)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1/language/%3?%1%4 [L]`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I did try it, however it didn't work. It's probably a bit more complex while the polylang plugin is rewriting the url with a wordpress action in php I think. [wordpress rewrite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule). I've disabled the polylang plugin for now looking for another solution.

Comment: May be. I don't know this plugin and wordpress at all :)